# How to add watermark to video with Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Android?

Tags: video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, watermark

I have recorded a video with camera in Xamarin Forms and want to add watermark logo at the bottom of the video. Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: I tried to use FFMpeg but it's nuget package for android has not been updated since 2017 and I was unable to add that nuget package in my Xamarin Android project.

Comment: I have no exp. in this but if I were to do such a thing I would let a separate service/server render the video with the watermark. So after you have the video it gets processed on a server and you get the video back with the watermark.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute layout? So you just overlap the video with a little image on top of it?

Comment: I did not try absolute layout. I do not want the image to overlap camera view while video is being recorded. I want to record video first and then apply image on video while saving.